# Battery capacity and duration

Tags: batteries

I have a light that needs to be powered by battery.  It is a 12V light that draws 4.5 A of current.  If I purchase a SLA battery that is 12V rated 5.0 Ah would that battery be sufficient?  I am confused on the whole Amp/hours rating.  Is a 5.0 Ah battery able to deliver 4.5 A of current?  And for how long?  Will be using deep cycles probably lighting the light for 10 seconds at a time.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: It depends what kind of light it is and the V vs I curve.

Comment: Unless you find the spec sheet that tell you the discharge rating, any attempt to infer it from capacity is only as good as a educated guess based on the type of battery.

Answer (score 1):

Your selected battery will be good to power your light for about 1 hour of continuous work. If you fire your light for 10 seconds, your battery will last for about 360 cycles.

The total capacity rating ("5 Ah") has little relationship with how much current the battery can deliver. I would guess that your SLA battery will be able to deliver much more than 4.5A.

CORRECTION: Tony is correct, the 5AH is usually based on 20-hours discharge time. This means that to get 5AH capacity, the discharge current shouldn't exceed 250 mA. Here is an example of typical [SLA 12V/5AH battery](http://www.battery-direct.com/Akku-Datenblatt/5-12.pdf). The datasheet says that the battery will last only 30 minutes under 5.7 A load, so the battery capacity gets down to 2.85 Ah. So at 4.5 A it might last about 40 minutes of continous discharge. Impulse-type discharge, however, is more favorable, so my initial estimate of 360 bursts might be correct.

The "initial current" of 1.5A is a requirement for charging mode. And, BTW, the battery under my reference can deliver 75 A, but for a really short time of 5 seconds.

Comment: It says on the battery "initial current less than 1.5 A".  That's where I am confused.  Would it deliver the 4.5 A needed when the switch is turned on?

Comment: no @NJG  It is under needed capacity for your load.

Comment: @NJG, yes, if this is a regular commercial-grade SLA battery, it will deliver 4.5 A, easily. See above.

Comment: Ali, I see your battery and data sheet.  But this makes it confusing.  You say yes, others say no.  Here is the battery I was going to purchase: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Lithonia-Lighting-ELB-1250A-R6-12-Volt-5-Amp-Replacement-Battery-ELB-1250A-R6/202942481

Comment: But others say I should get a higher Ah battery such as 15-20 Ah range instead of 5.  I'll only use it for maybe 15-30 times at 10 seconds of use before putting it on a charger.

Comment: @NJG, there is nothing to be confused. Most Lead-Acid batteries can have high discharge rate, this is in the physics of this type of batteries. For 30 10-seconds long discharges you can even buy a smaller battery. The battery I quoted can delver 20A for 5 minutes, all within specifications. Car batteries deliver 300-400 A every day. What is your concern? Are you making a spacecraft, or what?

Comment: I'm confused because someone else said I needed a higher Ah battery such as a 15 or 20.  The "initial current" stated on the battery I guess is what made me confused.  If you say that is for charging reference than I guess a 5Ah battery would be good.  Take a look at the battery I listed above and it should be good?  Thanks and sorry for being stubborn

Comment: @NJL, I asked you for a real datasheet. Where is it? Here is some other datasheet for you, http://www.tempestbatteries.com/html/tr5-12.html This is listed as substitute for Lithonia EBL 1250 battery. It says it can do >8A for 15 minutes, which is 900 seconds, or good for 90 times of your 10-s loads. What other proof do you need?

Answer (score 0):

AH rating = Amps*20 for 20 hour load the standard test time.

```
   Capacity = "5Ah"   >>>>>>>>  4Ah  >>> 3Ah 

(total hours * Amps = Ah)   
 20h* =    10h*  =     5h*  =      1h*  =     ?56 minutes 
 Amps Ah    Amps Ah    Amps Ah     Amps Ah    Amps  Ah
0.25  5.0   0.43 4.3   0.8  4.0    3.0  3.0   4.5   2.5?
```

So 10 second bursts of 4.5A may yield on  a fresh full charged "PowerSonic 5Ah SLA" about 150 amp-seconds or ~ 33 bursts.

[**Ref data**](http://www.power-sonic.com/images/powersonic/technical/1277751263_20100627-TechManual-Lo.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Tony, however it says on this battery "initial current less than 1.5 A". That's where I am confused. Would it deliver the 4.5 A needed when the switch is turned on?

Comment: @NJG, why don't you post a link to actual datasheet for your battery?

Comment: There are reasons why it states initial current must not exceed 0.3*C or 1.5A in your case so you need to do this or get a 15Ah rating besides at this rate you only get <50% capacity from SLA's

Comment: read your datasheet or mine if you don't understand. These are not LiPo's

Comment: Ok, so I would need a battery where on the specs it says it can deliver more than 4.5 A on initial current like this one?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/ExpertPower-EXP12180-Rechargeable-Battery-Bolts/dp/B00A82A3RK/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1505345010&sr=1-1&keywords=expertpower+battery+18ah

Comment: that's better....